# Splitting data to multiple sheets Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache poi for my spring mvc webapp. I am new to apache poi and I managed to generate data to .xls, the data is passed from my controller using `model`.

My goal is while the number of data generated reaches 25 row, I wanted to continue generates the next 25 row(26-50) to another sheet so on and so forth.

```
@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    int rnum = 1;

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + new Date() + ".xls\"");
    List<Employee> employeeList = (List<Employee>) model.get("empRecords");//get from my controller

    HSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee List"+rnum);
    setExcelHeader(excelSheet);
    setExcelRows(excelSheet, employeeList);
}

public void setExcelHeader(HSSFSheet excelSheet) {
    HSSFRow excelHeader = excelSheet.createRow(0);
    excelHeader.createCell(0).setCellValue("Id");
}

public void setExcelRows(HSSFSheet excelSheet, List<Employee> empList) {
    int record = 1;
    for (Employee a : empList) {
        HSSFRow excelRow = excelSheet.createRow(record++);
        excelRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(a.getId());
    }
}
```

Above is what I have done so far, how do I proceed further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass the workbook instead of the spreadsheet. this will allow you to create a new sheet in your function.

```
 public void setExcelRows(HSSFWorkbook wb, List<Employee> empList) {
    int record = 1; int sheetNum = 0;
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Employee List "+sheetNum);
    setExcelHeader(sheet);
    for (Employee a : empList) {
         if (record == 26){
             sheetNum++;
             sheet= wb.createSheet("Employee List "+ sheetNum);
             setExcelHeader(sheet);
             record = 1;
         }        
         HSSFRow excelRow = sheet.createRow(record++);
        excelRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(a.getId());
 }
```

}